# blackberry java wait screen (ActivityIndicatorView)

Tags: blackberry

how to add a activity screen to a button click event ?

```
            ActivityIndicatorView view = new ActivityIndicatorView(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        Bitmap spinImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("spinner.png");
        view.createActivityImageField(spinImage,6,0);
        LabelField label = new LabelField("Loading Hockey...");
        s.add(label);
        s.add(view);
        pushScreen(s);
```

by this code, it will shows error. ie no import package 
how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you importing all the right packages? i.e.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.progressindicator.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
```

and so on....

Comment: This package is new to BlackBerry 6. You're probably not compiling against the right set of runtime libraries. You'll need to update your project to use the OS 6 APIs.